# sharing STS claim authentication across SharePoint and asp.net application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

My requirement is to share the claims authentication between SharePoint and other asp.net application.

Actually, I have built my custom STS. and claims authentication works fine. but, just that I am not sure how to share this authentication between SharePoint and my other .asp net application (which is also claims aware) and also vice versa where I get authenticated using asp.net application but I stil prompts for sharepoint even though both are configured for same STS provider. Any pointers on this?

Answer (score 1):

which version of SharePoint are you referring?

1) In SharePoint 2010 and earlier it was possible to edit the users directly from a SharePoint web application site, as long as the default membership provider was set to the membership provider you were going to edit.

2) This is no longer possible in SharePoint 2013, as previous versions of SharePoint ran against ASP.NET 2.0 (3.5), but SharePoint 2013 runs on ASP.NET 4.0.  IIS does not support editing users and roles for ASP.NET 4.0 applications. To get around this, we’ll create a dummy/blank ASP.NET 2.0 web site just for editing users.
The asp.net 2.0 and 4.0 membership databases are exactly the same, which makes this possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for single sign-on with windows identity foundation.
For example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/windows-identity-foundation-and-single-sign-on-sso/

There is a good description in the ["Programming Windows Identity Foundation (Developer Reference)" by Vittorio Bertocci](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735627185)